# how to covert following curl script to php curl script?

Tags: php, curl

can any one help me to convert following curl code to php curl script?

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxx/SMS/Messages.xml' \
-d 'From=%2Byyyy' \
-d 'To=%2Bxxxx' \
-d 'Body=Dear%2C+Plz+wake+up%3B+it'\''s+time+4+SAHERI.%0D%0AYour+1+night+sacrifice+will+make+thousands+night+wonderful+by+the+grace+of+almighty+ALLAH.%0D%0A%0D%0A-biplob+(%2Bxxxxx)' \
-u xxx:yyy
```

best regards
MD Kamrul Hassan

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

The options you'd need set on your curl handle are as follows.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxx/SMS/Messages.xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('From' => 'blah', 'To' => 'blih', 'Body' => 'Please wake up whatever'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');
```

Comment: hi, Lusitanian thaks a lot for your help, i m facing a error on folloing line:
 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('From' => '%2B11111135135', 'To' => '%2B1101111219006', 'Body' => "Dear%2C+Plz+wake+up%3B+it'\''s+time+4+SAHERI.%0D%0AYour+1+night+sacrifice+will+make+thousands+night+wonderful+by+the+grace+of+almighty+ALLAH.%0D%0A%0D%0A-biplob+(%2B1101111219006)");

 i got an error and it says:
 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home6/siamcomp/public_html/etc/asms.php on line x (the line where we define post fields

Comment: sir, i did found the probleb, in your sample, you didn't close the array with brackets ..

Comment: but now another issue, post field value for "body" is not same when i used that direct curl command.. in curl it's lesss than 160 char, but when using your code (php) it says character is larger than 160 .. can you help please?

Comment: I think a lot of options are still missing. 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type:multipart/form-data'
    )); if you send post feilds in an array and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER for https connections